# Don't modify string if a character appeared previously

Tags: python, string, data-cleaning

I have a string which looks like this:

```
street.Random, street.Randomer: 2, 4
```

I need to split it into:

```
street.Random 
street.Randomer: 2, 4
```

I **can't** do on the first apparence of `,` since the number of them can be random.

I looked at a way of detective if `:` appeared recently (or at all) in the string and then somehow split it based on that, but not sure how.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by random number of `,`. Are you expecting strings like "street.Random,,," or "street.Random,,,,,"? Please give some examples of why splitting on the first `,` won't work.

Comment: Could you take the index of `:`and split the string by the last `,` before the index of `;`

Comment: The possible data can be `street.Random, street.RandomTwo, street.Randomer: 2, 4` .This is what I meant by not possible to split on first `,`.

Comment: I can't be certain what the index xof `:` will be thought. I can be certain it will be there but not certain at what position.

Comment: @ArcLight_Slavik What should be the result if the data is `street.Random, street.RandomTwo, street.Randomer: 2, 4`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely There separate strings, `['street.Random', 'street.RandomTwo', 'street.Randomer: 2, 4']`

Comment: @ArcLight_Slavik See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count number of `,` till first `:` and then do `str.split()` with `maxsplit=count` parameter"

```
s = 'street.Random, street.RandomTwo, street.Randomer: 2, 4'

count = 0
for ch in s:
    if ch == ':':
        break
    elif ch == ',':
        count += 1

print( [*map(str.strip, s.split(',', maxsplit=count))] )
```

Prints:

```
['street.Random', 'street.RandomTwo', 'street.Randomer: 2, 4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the 3rd-party `regex` module with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
import regex
s = 'street.Random, street.RandomTwo, street.Randomer: 2, 4'
print(regex.split(r'\d,(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,',s))
```

Output:

```
['street.Random', ' street.RandomTwo', ' street.Randomer: 2, 4']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rOSWek/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below 5 steps:-

1. Split the string at the ':' and save the first element of the resulting split in another string(s1).
2. Split the string s1 at the spaces and save the second last element in another string(s2).
3. Print all the elements of s1(after splitting s1) with a space between each element until the second last element.
4. Print the string s2 until the second last character(to omit the comma(,)) in the same line as step 3.
5. Split the original string(at the spaces) and print the last three elements on a new line with a space between them.

Here is the code snippet for better understanding the above steps:

```
    s = 'street.Random, street.Random2, street.Random3, street.Randomer: 2, 4'
    s1 = s.split(':')[0]                                          # Step 1
    s2 = s1.split()[-2]                                           # Step 2
    print(' '.join(i for i in s1.split()[:-2]), end = ' ')        # Step 3
    print(s2[:-1])                                                # Step 4
    print(' '.join(s.split()[-3:]))                               # Step 5
```